# How best to process dynamic query parameters using Java & Spring

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, http, query-string

**The problem:**

I have an api endpoint which handles multiple query parameters. It is implemented using Spring, and the query parameters are used to query data from a postgres database, which I query with a JDBC Template.

I am searching for a mature query builder technology to solve my problem.

**Example:**

A trivial query could look something like this:

```
api/book?name=LOTR&cover=hardback
```

The query parameters are added to a map, and a query string is build from the maps data:

```
String sqlQuery += (String) map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "='" + entry.getValue() + "' AND ")
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Its not the most efficient, as I must always remove the trailing `"AND"` clause from the string, but it works.

However, if the query where to look something like

```
api/book?name=LOTR&name=Ulysses&cover=hardback
```

there is now the addition of an `"OR"` clause, which the above code would not handle. I can see myself quickly getting into the territory of with tedious string parsing to create SQL statements.

So now that I have presented my problem, I wonder if there is a technology I can use which handles this kind of problem nicely?

I would like to avoid the use of any ORM for this project, so Hibernate and MyBatis are out of the question. I have looked at some JOOQ examples, but they do not look compatible with JDBC Template.

Answer (score 0):

For trivial implementations like your first case where you have to remove last AND after your query is built there is a simple hack - immediately after WHERE you add 1 = 1 and then for every WHERE predicate you add AND [COLUMN] = [VALUE].

Note: most databases optimise use of constants in WHERE clause before execution, so performance will not be an issue

```
/*
  select <columns> from <tables> where 1 = 1
  [dynamically built Where predicates will come here from following code] 
*/

String sqlQuery += (String) map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> "AND " + entry.getKey() + "='" + entry.getValue() + "'")
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

However for serious production implementations you may want to use frameworks like myBatis that gives you possibilities of templating a query and then passing parameters at runtime to build final queries.

You can find a good tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mybatis/index.htm).

```
/* An example */
<select id = "getName_Id_phone" parameterType = "Student" resultType = "Student">
   SELECT * FROM STUDENT    
   <where>
      <if test = "id != null">
         id = #{id}
      </if>
      <if test = "name != null">
         AND name LIKE #{name}
      </if>
   </where>     
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across here with the same question. Maybe you want to take a look at RSQL [1](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser)

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer. Not only a link.